# Show that $x^2-dy^2 = -2$ with $d = m^2+2$ has infinitetly many integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I want to show that for $d= m^2+2$ the equation

> $$x^2-dy^2 = -2$$

has infinitetly many integer solutions. 
By trying out one can see that $x=\pm m, y=\pm 1$ are solutions, but how do we know that there exist infinitely many solutions?

I have already studied the similar equation $x^2 -dy^2=1$ and shown that for that a fundamental solution is given by $(m^2+1, m)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $d\in\Bbb N$ is not a square, and
$$x^2-dy^2=k\tag1$$
has some integer solution for $k\ne 0$ then $(1)$ has infinitely many
integer solutions. This is because Pell's equation
$$x^2-dy^2=1\tag2$$
has infinitely many integer
solutions, and if $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution to $(1)$
and $(x_2,y_2)$ is a solution to $(2)$ then $(x_1x_2+dy_1y_2,x_1y_2+y_1x_2)$ is also a solution to $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean "is also a solution to $(1)$" in the end?

Comment: How did you come up with looking at $(x_1x_2 + dy_2y_2, x_1y_2 + y_1x_2)$?

Comment: There is a typo; please fix it.. On the last line, it should say $dy_1 y_2$ instead of $d y_2 y_2$.